# MSSQL: Condition inside or outside the Subquery

Tags: sql-server, subquery, conditional-statements

Below 2 options gave me the same results, and execution time is almost the same.
Please advise me which one is better in terms of performance

**OPTION A: Condition is in the subqueries.**
**EXECUTION TIME: 3 SECS**

```
SELECT 
a.Sales_ID, a.Sales_No, a.Sales, b.Collection
FROM
(
    SELECT Month, Sales_ID, Sales_No, Sum(Sales) 'Sales'
    FROM FT_Sales a
    JOIN LU_Month b on a.Day=b.Day
    WHERE b.Month=201607
    GROUP BY Month, Sales_ID, Sales_No
) a
JOIN
(
    SELECT Month, Sales_ID, Sales_No, Sum(Collection) 'Collection'
    FROM FT_Payment a
    JOIN LU_Month b on a.Day=b.Day
    WHERE b.Month=201607
    GROUP BY Month, Sales_ID, Sales_No
) b on a.Sales_ID=b.Sales_ID
```

**OPTION B: Condition is outside the subqueries.
EXECUTION TIME: 3 SECS**

```
SELECT 
a.Sales_ID, a.Sales_No, a.Sales, b.Collection
FROM
(
    SELECT b.Month, Sales_ID, Sales_No, Sum(Sales) 'Sales'
    FROM FT_Sales a
    JOIN LU_Month b on a.Day=b.Day
    GROUP BY b.Month, Sales_ID, Sales_No
) a
JOIN
(
    SELECT b.Month, Sales_ID, Sales_No, Sum(Collection) 'Collection'
    FROM FT_Payment a
    JOIN LU_Month b on a.Day=b.Day
    GROUP BY b.Month, Sales_ID, Sales_No
) b on a.Sales_ID=b.Sales_ID AND a.Month=b.Month
WHERE a.Month=201607
```

Comment: I don't believe there is a difference here, but the difference would come into play with other types of joins. e.g. A where clause in the subquery of a left join will still show all results from the other table, a where clause outside the subquery of a left join is essentially an inner join.

Comment: What does the plan say?

Comment: In SQL, you tell the system *what you want*, not *how to do it*. Assuming everything is running sensibly, the optimizer *should* generate identical plans for these - because they both ask for the same *logical* result.

Answer (score 0):

Unless there is something that is present with indexing, etc. that is out of the ordinary, Option A would be better. Eliminate rows before doing aggregate operations or joining the subqueries. Also, if you choose Option A, you do not need to group by month either.

Wondering too, without seeing the data structure or data, why you have to join to LU_Month to pull the month? If it just the calendar you can use datepart function to get the month from FT_Payment.day. If the day is some sort of "since the system was turned on" day counter, you can still use date functions to calc the month. Might speed you up from using an expensive join to get a month. Just a suggestion.

Comment: Nothing out of ordinary here, it's a feature of SQL Server's optimizer called "predicate pushing" at work

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, Hope this will help you.

```
SELECT 
a.Sales_ID, a.Sales_No, SUM(a.Sales) AS Sales, SUM(a.Collection) AS Collection
FROM
(
    SELECT Month, Sales_ID, Sales_No, Sum(Sales) AS 'Sales', 0 AS 'Collection'
    FROM FT_Sales a
    JOIN LU_Month b on a.Day=b.Day
    WHERE b.Month=201607
    GROUP BY Month, Sales_ID, Sales_No
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Month, Sales_ID, Sales_No, 0  AS 'Sales' , Sum(Collection) AS 'Collection'
    FROM FT_Payment a
    JOIN LU_Month b on a.Day=b.Day
    WHERE b.Month=201607
    GROUP BY Month, Sales_ID, Sales_No
) as a
```